# How to disable Azure Portal environment

Tags: azure, azureportal

Is it possible to Inactivate Azure Portal particular environment. Like, only development environment and whenever need then, re-activate again ?

Reason is like, its not going to use for next couple of month so, would like to make it disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at  **[`DevTest Labs`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devtest-lab/)** which you could  configure and use it whenever you want.

Fast, easy, and lean dev-test environments in Azure.Specifically for your team which can be run On demand.

**EDIT:**

Simple answer is **NO**. However when you are using ARM templates to create the resources and do the deployment those resources will be created again. Usually Azure Paas is more about Pay as you go.I do not see a requirement to disable those and activate again.

Comment: Is it possible to disable this environment completely so, no one can hit. Whenever needed then only, explicitly enable ?

Comment: yes you can https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-devtest-labs-configure-enforcing-auto-shutdown-schedule-for-your-lab/

Comment: Cn you share me the steps that can shutdown and allow to re-activate environment ?

Comment: Basically this will disable the VM, But I need to disable only, resources like, FunctionApp OR COMOSDB? Is there way to do ?